# Jenkins artifact short URL / pretty url

Tags: jenkins, url, build, artifact, bitly

How to get a direct short URL for the jenkins build output file.

My last successful build is located at this path.

https://jenkins.domain.com/job/Org_repo_folder/job/project/job/release/build_number/artifact/ApplicationModule/build/outputs/apk/release/AppName_version.apk

How do I access the file with a short URL or path?

Use case:

1. Long url exposes the build path.
2. Emails with long urls ends at spam folder.
3. Build sharing with simple URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a Jenkins-internal solution, then you could use the [`userContent`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/user-content/) feature.

E.g., Jenkins serves data under `$JENKINS_HOME/userContent/file.apk` under the URL `$JENKINS_URL/userContent/file.apk`.

If you copy (or symlink) the data that you want to provide to `$JENKINS_HOME/userContent/`, then you can use the `userContent` URL as a short URL for that.

Comment: Hello Alex, not internal. But to send the build (apk) as url. Right now, the latest release path as url is very long and the mail end up as spam.

Comment: So, as I suggested, the userContent solution can be used to provide a shorter URL.

Comment: Hi Alex, I confirm the userContent works can be used to reduce the url length. What I did is, I copied the output apk to the userContent folder and referred that by url.

But this results in file duplication. Also I'm cleaning up the older files.

Comment: No other way to get direct reference but with a short URL ? Much appreciated.

Else I'll mark this as the answer!

Comment: If you use a symlink (e.g. to the `lastSuccessfulBuild` artifacts path), then you don't have to copy/update the data in `userContent`, and there's no duplication either. I'm not aware of other options for providing a short URL with Jenkins.